# XSD(maxOccurs=(specify large value))- java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: xsd, xerces, jaxb2

when we deploy the application on tomcat server I have been facing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError issue because  **we specify large values for "maxOccurs" attribute(i.e. maxOccurs="999999")in the schema definition**. Please find below sample snippet and the exception stack trace. Could someone please suggest optimized solution to avoid this scenario.

Initially we kept maxoccurs value to "unbound". But when we scan code base with HP Fortify Static Code Analyzer we found there is Critical issue(for more info on the issue please visit:[Fortify Link](http://www.hpenterprisesecurity.com/vulncat/en/vulncat/index.html), on the left panel we have XML-->Environment--> **Weak XML Schema: Unbounded Occurrences**). So HP Foritfy tool **recommends limit maxoccurs to a reasonable number.** we have to fix this issue to get sign off from business.

```
Java version: JDK 1.6.0_30
Tomcat Version: 6.0
```

**Note: please don’t suggest to increase heap size. The current scenario I am facing is in development tomcat application server, where as in production tomcat application server I don’t see this issue(may be production server has more space)**

```
  Schema1.xsd  

      <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name=" User " type=" UserType " maxOccurs="999999"/>
                          <!-- maxOccurs we specifying large number-->
      </xs:sequence>
```

Exception Stack Trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
     at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.models.CMStateSet.<init>(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.models.XSDFACM.buildDFA(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.models.XSDFACM.<init>(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.models.CMBuilder.createDFACM(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.models.CMBuilder.getContentModel(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XSComplexTypeDecl.getContentModel(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XSConstraints.fullSchemaChecking(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)
     at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:594)
     at com.prac.app.common.xmlsupport.SchemaLoaderImpl.init(SchemaLoaderImpl.java:92)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple change:  set `maxOccurs` to `unbounded` instead of a large number.  (If the validator is building a heavy-weight representation of a finite state automaton, then your current declaration requires a million states; `maxOccurs="unbounded"` reduces that to one state.  If your current schema routinely catches errors caused by documents with more than 999,999 User elements, changing to `unbounded` will weaken your validation, of course.

Comment: I updated my query why we couldn't set maxoccurs to unbound.Anyway thank you for your time to look into this.

Comment: Have you tried changing 999999 to 99 to see if that helps?  How many occurrences of `User` do you actually expect?  Can you really process a million User elements (and if so, is `unbounded` really unsafe for this application?), or is setting maxOccurs to 999999 your way of getting the Fortify warning to go away without actually thinking about the security issue it's raising?